# Why the onClick does not work with my RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the issue with my RecyclerView item onClick event. Here is my adapter class:

```
class CategoryRecyclerAdapter( val listener: (position: Int) -> Unit):
RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

private var catTitles = arrayOf(
    "lorem ipsum cat one",
    "lorem ipsum cat otwo",
    "lorem ipsum cat three",
    "lorem ipsum cat four",
    "lorem ipsum cat five",
    "lorem ipsum cat six"
)

private var catImages = arrayOf(
    R.drawable.ic_star,
    R.drawable.ic_star,
    R.drawable.ic_star,
    R.drawable.ic_star,
    R.drawable.ic_star,
    R.drawable.ic_star
)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.catTitle.text = catTitles[position]
    holder.catImage.setImageResource(catImages[position])
    when(position){
        0 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5668"))
        }
        1 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18C2E9"))
        }
        2 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#686DF6"))
        }
        3 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA925"))
        }
        4 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18C2E9"))
        }
        5 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5668"))
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return catTitles.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener{
    var catImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catImage)
    var catTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catTitle)
    var catCard: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catCardItem)

    override fun onClick(viewType: View?) {
        listener.invoke(adapterPosition)
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my mainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val categoryList = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mainCategoryGrid)

    categoryList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2).also {
        it.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return if (position == 4 )
                    2
                else if (position == 5)
                    2
                else
                    1
            }
        }
    }

    categoryList.adapter = CategoryRecyclerAdapter { position ->

        val topActivity = Intent(this, TopActivity::class.java)
        val flowersAlphabetActivity = Intent(this, FlowersActivity::class.java)
        val readActivity = Intent(this, ReadActivity::class.java)
        val commonActivity = Intent(this, CommonActivity::class.java)
        val stepperActivity = Intent(this, StepperActivity::class.java)
        val phrasesActivity = Intent(this, PhrasesActivity::class.java)

        when (position) {
            0 -> startActivity(alphabetActivity)
            1 -> startActivity(flowersAlphabetActivity)
            2 -> startActivity(readActivity)
            3 -> startActivity(commonActivity)
            4 -> startActivity(stepperActivity)
            5 -> startActivity(phrasesActivity)
        }
     }

   }
 }
```

In the app before I used the same structure for implement the RecyclerView item onClick Listener and it work pretty well. Now this code does not works. Maybe the issue generate because I'm using spanSizeLookup in this case. Please help to figure out why it does not work now.

PS: I know there are a lot info about RecyclerView Item Click Listener on Stackoverflow but I do not ask how to target this goal I just need to figure out why my code does not work. And one more I just dive into android development, and I use only Kotlin not Java.

Comment: You are not initializing click event to any view, in the onBindViewHolder, initialize click listener to the view

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Thanks you,  it is really works now. Only one line of the code: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { listener(position) }

Answer (score 0):

I'm Java Developer so I cannot code with Kotlin but I'll show you how can you change `cardView` background on `Onclick`.

You are directly using conditions without any `itemView`.

just put your condition in `holder.itemView.setOnClickListner`. See below code

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
Toast.makeText(context, "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   when(position){
        0 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5668"))
        }
        1 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18C2E9"))
        }
        2 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#686DF6"))
        }
        3 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA925"))
        }
        4 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18C2E9"))
        }
        5 -> {
            holder.catCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5668"))
        }
    }

});
```

Make sure to change `JAVA` to `Kotlin` in my code. If you any problem is causing, Let me know

Answer (score 0):

**Add Click listner in recylerview**

```
private lateinit var mListener: OnItemClickListener

    interface OnItemClickListener : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) {
        mListener = listener
    }
```

**And Then**

**You can simply use this for your click listner of recylerview in** `MainActivity`.

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : CategoryRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
               
                override fun onClick(position: Int) {
                   when (position) {
                         0 -> startActivity(alphabetActivity)
                         1 -> startActivity(flowersAlphabetActivity)
                         2 -> startActivity(readActivity)
                         3 -> startActivity(commonActivity)
                         4 -> startActivity(stepperActivity)
                         5 -> startActivity(phrasesActivity)
                   }
                }
    
               
            })
```

(Need to change Function and variable name)

Hope it will work for you.